# Dialogflow Google Assistant crashes

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk

I made a chatbot with dialogflow and this is working normal. Then i add Google Assistant on a respond like: -Hey, Google Assistant answers with Suggestion Chips: -Hey. When i open this appliation on android phone, i can write normally and i can see normal answers. But when i try to write "Hey" or something when i save for Google Assistant, application crashes. Could it be caused by the API version? Why this is happenning?
Codes:

```
public class clsPrincipal extends AppCompatActivity implements AIListener, View.OnClickListener {
private ImageButton btnVoice;
private ImageButton sendmessage;
private AIService aiService;
private static final int REQUEST_INTERNET = 200;


TextToSpeech t1;

public static String TAG = "AndroidDialogflow";

List<Message> lista;
ListView milista;
EditText message;
AIConfiguration config;


public static String API_KEY="032d9af645ac46739a1b2d576d5ff224";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fprincipal);
    btnVoice = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sendspeacker);
    lista = new ArrayList<>();

    validateOS();

    config = new AIConfiguration(API_KEY,
            AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
            AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);

    aiService = AIService.getService(this, config);
    aiService.setListener(this);
    milista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chat);
    sendmessage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sendmessage);
    sendmessage.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnVoice.setOnClickListener(this);
    t1 = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                Locale locSpanish = new Locale("spa", "MEX");
                t1.setLanguage(locSpanish);
            }
        }
    });

    message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textmessage);


}

private void validateOS() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(clsPrincipal.this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(clsPrincipal.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, REQUEST_INTERNET);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(clsPrincipal.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, REQUEST_INTERNET);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResult(AIResponse response) {
    Result result = response.getResult();
    final Status status = response.getStatus();
    Log.i(TAG, "Status code: " + status.getCode());
    Log.i(TAG, "Status type: " + status.getErrorType());
    final Metadata metadata = result.getMetadata();
    if (metadata != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Intent id: " + metadata.getIntentId());
        Log.i(TAG, "Intent name: " + metadata.getIntentName());
    }
    String parameterString = "";
    if (result.getParameters() != null && !result.getParameters().isEmpty()) {
        for (final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : result.getParameters().entrySet()) {
            parameterString += "(" + entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue();
        }
    }
    String cad = response.getResult().getFulfillment().getSpeech().toString();
    if (cad.compareTo("") == 0) {
        cad = "Hata meydana geldi";
    }
    // text to speech get text response
    t1.speak(cad, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    lista.add(new Message(result.getResolvedQuery(), 1));
    lista.add(new Message(cad, 0));
    AdapMessage adap = new AdapMessage(lista, this);
    milista.setAdapter(adap);
}

@Override
public void onError(AIError error) {
    Log.e(TAG,error.toString());
}

@Override
public void onAudioLevel(float level) {

}

@Override
public void onListeningStarted() {

}

@Override
public void onListeningCanceled() {

}

@Override
public void onListeningFinished() {

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.sendspeacker:
            aiService.startListening();
            break;
        case R.id.sendmessage:
            SendText(message.getText().toString());
            break;
    }
}

void SendText(String query) {
    final AIConfiguration config = new AIConfiguration(API_KEY,
            AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
            AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);
    final AIDataService aiDataService = new AIDataService(this,config);
    final AIRequest aiRequest = new AIRequest();
    aiRequest.setQuery(query);

    new AsyncTask<AIRequest, Void, AIResponse>() {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(clsPrincipal.this);
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Mesaj gönderiliyor...");
            this.dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected AIResponse doInBackground(AIRequest... requests) {
            final AIRequest request = requests[0];
            try {
                final AIResponse response = aiDataService.request(aiRequest);
                return response;
            } catch (AIServiceException e) {
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(AIResponse aiResponse) {
            if (aiResponse != null) {
                // process aiResponse here
                Result result = aiResponse.getResult();
                String cad = aiResponse.getResult().getFulfillment().getSpeech().toString();
                if (cad.compareTo("") == 0) {
                    cad = "Hata oluştu";
                }
                t1.speak(cad, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                lista.add(new Message(result.getResolvedQuery(), 1));
                lista.add(new Message(cad, 0));
                AdapMessage adap = new AdapMessage(lista, clsPrincipal.this);
                milista.setAdapter(adap);
                if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                message.setText("");

            }
        }
    }.execute(aiRequest);
}
}
```

**Logcat:**

```
12-08 10:13:04.965 8476-8533/com.codigopanda.androiddialogflow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
Process: com.codigopanda.androiddialogflow, PID: 8476
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "suggestion_chips"
    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
    at com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive.getAsInt(JsonPrimitive.java:260)
    at ai.api.GsonFactory$ResponseItemAdapter.deserialize(GsonFactory.java:78)
    at ai.api.GsonFactory$ResponseItemAdapter.deserialize(GsonFactory.java:71)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
    at ai.api.AIDataService.request(AIDataService.java:193)
    at ai.api.AIDataService.request(AIDataService.java:148)
    at ai.api.AIDataService.request(AIDataService.java:124)
    at com.berkancalikoglu.mesajlas.clsPrincipal$2.doInBackground(clsPrincipal.java:175)
    at com.berkancalikoglu.mesajlas.clsPrincipal$2.doInBackground(clsPrincipal.java:167)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
12-08 10:13:04.967 2002-3970/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.codigopanda.androiddialogflow/com.berkancalikoglu.mesajlas.clsPrincipal
12-08 10:13:04.974 1269-1425/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 331776
12-08 10:13:04.986 1269-1269/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1269: eglCreateSyncKHR(1881): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
12-08 10:13:05.123 8476-8520/com.codigopanda.androiddialogflow D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f864d962fa0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f864d943900)
12-08 10:13:05.131 8476-8520/com.codigopanda.androiddialogflow E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f864d963720
12-08 10:13:05.137 2002-6238/system_process I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-08 10:13:05.139 2002-6238/system_process D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7f863907b400: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
12-08 10:13:05.142 8476-8520/com.codigopanda.androiddialogflow D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7f8641336000 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7f8640f3e8c0
12-08 10:13:05.145 2002-6238/system_process D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f863907b400: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f863ba2bb60)
12-08 10:13:05.159 2002-6238/system_process D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f863907b400: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f863ba2bb60)
12-08 10:13:05.188 3194-3283/com.android.launcher3 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f864a0dc060: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f864271e960)
12-08 10:13:05.266 2002-2014/system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
12-08 10:13:07.880 1693-1992/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 20467322 , only wrote 20330377
12-08 10:13:07.891 8476-8533/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8476 SIG: 9
12-08 10:13:07.894 2002-6238/system_process D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f863907b400: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f863ba2bb60)
12-08 10:13:07.896 2002-6238/system_process E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f863ba05200
12-08 10:13:07.916 2002-2340/system_process D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 4
12-08 10:13:07.919 2002-2231/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 8476 uid 10064
12-08 10:13:07.934 1693-1992/? D/AudioFlinger: mixer(0xf4300000) throttle end: throttle time(11)
12-08 10:13:07.946 2002-2338/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process com.codigopanda.androiddialogflow (pid 8476) has died
12-08 10:13:07.954 2570-5483/com.android.inputmethod.latin D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f864a0dc420: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f86519bfca0)
12-08 10:13:07.955 2378-2883/com.android.systemui D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f86414dcaa0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f8641a963e0)
12-08 10:13:07.958 2570-5483/com.android.inputmethod.latin E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f86409a32c0
12-08 10:13:08.091 2002-2023/system_process W/AppOps: Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 1000 pkg android code 24 time=0 duration=0 nesting=0
12-08 10:13:08.357 2378-2883/com.android.systemui D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f86414dcaa0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f8641a963e0)
12-08 10:13:11.040 1693-1992/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 20604829 , only wrote 20468526
```

Comment: I do not see where you're using the Google Assistant, and you didn't provide the stacktrace either, which would be useful to identify the cause of the crash. Can you add more details?

Comment: Thank you for advice. I really don't know how and where to add stacktrace and Google Assistant. You are seeing my codes already. Can you help me with that?

Comment: As this seems to be an Android app, you should see a Logcat button in Android Studio which will show you logs.

Comment: I added logcat on topic

Comment: I'm not sure where you're setting suggestion chips, but it looks like you're not doing it the right way.

Comment: I setted on console.dialogflow.com . But i didnt use any code with that. How should i use this?

Comment: I think the issue may be in your source code, in an asynctask.

Comment: I gived to you my codes, can you try to run with Google Assistant and suggestion chips?

Comment: Your issue is somewhere in your asynctask, in the `doInBackground` method

Comment: Maybe i could make this on my project? https://github.com/androidthings/sample-googleassistant

Comment: That project isn't exactly the same thing, but you could try it